# PHP Form Posts to MySQL Database Successfully, But Adds Blank Rows sometimes when registering

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Form Posts to MySQL Database Successfully, But Adds Blank Rows sometimes when registering.
here is my code:

```
include("includes/db.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $hidden == "" ) {
    $product = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_POST['product']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_POST['name']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_POST['address']);
    $coupon = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_POST['coupon']);      

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if (isset($_FILES["invoice_copy"]["name"])) {
        $imgpancard = $_FILES["invoice_copy"]["name"];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['invoice_copy']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES['invoice_copy']['error'];

        if (!empty($imgpancard)) {
            $location = 'doc/';

            if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$imgpancard)){
                //echo 'Uploaded';
            }

        } 
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE  coupon='".$coupon."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

        echo'<script> alert("COUPON ALEARDY EXISTS!");
        window.location="register.php";
        </script> ';
    }
    else {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (product, customer_name, address,  coupon, RegistrationDate, invoice_copy) VALUES ('$product', '$name', '$address', '$coupon', '$dates', '$imgpancard')";
        if(mysqli_query($bd, $sql)){
            echo'<script> alert("DATA SUBMITTED SUCCESFULLY!");
            window.location="index.html"; </script> ';
        } 
        else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($bd);
        }
    }
}
```

how to of 10 times one times blank data is inserted.how to avoid it can please tell me , whether code is wrong or not. In every input feild i have used required attribute

Comment: I every input feild i have used required attribute

Comment: In Db structure, is NUll allowed for all fields ?

Comment: I have set not null to all fields   `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

Comment: why no restriction on mysql side...? seems like ur script is executed multiple times...

Comment: `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

Comment: how to avoid it